# How to detect when all CloudKit Updates happened?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

In my code i'm using `func fetchDatabaseChanges`
and `func fetchZoneChanges` methods described at this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/MaintainingaLocalCacheofCloudKitRecords/MaintainingaLocalCacheofCloudKitRecords.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH12-SW1)

I need to send a notification after all fetches and changes of CloudKit records happened. I don't understand clearly where should I put this call?

In `operation.recordZoneFetchCompletionBlock`or maybe in `operation.recordChangedBlock` ?

This send notification call should happen after all updates happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You find your answer in the documentation here.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/SubscribingtoRecordChanges/SubscribingtoRecordChanges.html

In short you setup a subscription to cloudKit code and then register thru the appDelegate for remote notifications. And than finally setup the code to handle them when you get them.